# DropDown List does not bind ajax data source

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

Here is my Drop downlist (kendo) and I also attached my screen shot of data I get,the result I get in drop down list is "undifiend",

```
function deviceTypesList(container, options) {
                        $('<input  name="DeviceType" data-type="string" \">')
                          .appendTo(container)
                          .kendoDropDownList({
                              dataSource:mydata_deviceType,
                              dataTextField: "Value",
                              dataValueField: "Value",

                              //dataValueField: "ProductName",


                          });
```

**Screen shot**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your values are actually stored in the property "model" you need to tell it to the kendo dropdownlist.

So instead of

```
//...
dataTextField: "Value",
dataValueField: "Value",
//...
```

do this

```
//...
dataTextField: "model",
dataValueField: "model",
//...
```

Another way would be remapping your array to an array of objects with the property "Value".

Eg.

```
mydata_deviceType = mydata_deviceType.map(function(x) {
    return {
        Value: x.model
    };
});
```